# How to fix 'unknown' function values with other functions in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, compilation

I have a main function that does all the processing, which a bunch of other methods will use.

The only problem, however, is that "I don't know what unknown" is according to the TypeScript compiler.

```
async function main_function(url: string): Promise<unknown> {
  // doComplexStuff();
  const data = await fetch(url);
  return data.json();
}
```

The problems arises when I want to modify these functions' types.

```
function req_1(url: string): Promise<something> { return main_function(url); }
function req_2(url: string): Promise<other> { return main_function(url); }
function req_3(url: string): Promise<blah_blah> { return main_function(url); }
```

As far as I'm aware, I can do this with type parameter on function syntax, or the `as` way, but those seem more as a workaround nor are they as elegant.

Comment: What you're proposing isn't type safe, so anything you do to make this compile will probably be a "workaround" in that respect.  Have you considered having `main_function()` return `Promise<any>` instead of `Promise<unknown>`?  This is also not type safe, but will allow `req_1` et al to compile.

Comment: Well, I generally try avoiding the use `any` anywhere in my code because like you said it's not type safe.

Comment: If you use `data.json()` you are using `any`. The only way to make your code type safe is to add explicit type guard code that runs in JS which makes sure the value that comes out is really a `something` (and if you want some concrete examples in an answer you might want to make your code a [mcve] with some definitions for those types).  If all you are going to do is modify the types without changing emitted JS then you are giving up type safety already at which point it's up to your personal opinion about elegance whether or not you want `any`, a specified type parameter, or a type assertion.

Comment: You were proposing I use `Promise<any>` for the return value which I should've clarified in my original comment that that's what I was avoiding. Unfortunately the only type safe solution is to cram my other functions with if statements, in Travis's comment.

Answer (score 0):

`data.json()` returns type `any`, so there's no way for Typescript to determine what the output type is supposed to be unless you explicitly tell it.

Your best option then is to use generics, and preferably to guard the type that gets returned to ensure that it is in fact what you expect it to be.

```
async function main_function<T = unknown>(url: string): Promise<T> {
  // doComplexStuff();
  const data = await fetch(url);
  return data.json();
}
function req_1(url: string): Promise<something> { return main_function(url); }
function req_2(url: string): Promise<other> { return main_function(url); }
function req_3(url: string): Promise<blah_blah> { return main_function(url); }
```

Note that you don't have to specify `main_function<something>`, because it can be inferred by Typescript based on the expected result of the req functions (`Promise<something>`).

As I mentioned, it is probably better to check that the results are of the correct type also, such as:

```
function req_1(url: string): Promise<something> {
  const result = main_function(url);
  if (/* result is something */) {
    throw new Error('Got a response that was not of type \'something\'')
  }
  return result
}
```

Comment: It would be possible to do those checks within `main_function` right? I don't want to write down a bunch of if statements in my other methods that use main_function.

Comment: @Helicopter whilst it would be possible, depending on how much the types differ it may not be recommended.

This may not be the objectively correct answer, but if I were doing something similar I would do the following:
- Make `main_function` return `Promise<unknown>`
- Create a "type gaurd" function (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) for each non-primitive type
- Use the type guards in each of your request functions, such as in the second example I gave in place of `/* result is something */`